# Include meta in search results and related questions?

Tags: feature-request, usability

There are a lot of questions that get closed as "belongs on uservoice" now "belongs on meta" that would simply not exist if the search results and Related Question hints that show up when you ask a question simply included the meta questions as well. Many of them are legitimate questions about the use or etiquette of SO. New users aren't familiar with meta. . While the "feedback always welcome" link is inviting for offering feedback, its not obvious that it's the location for asking questions about the site.

Answer (score 5):

Naw, let's not do that.

If we show meta search results in with SO search results, folks will just stay on SO for their meta-SO tasks, including asking more meta-SO questions on SO proper. Which kinda defeats the whole purpose of *having* a meta-SO.

Close 'em, with prejudice, and send 'em this way - then they can stay, if that's what they *really* want...

Comment: The meta results can be clearly identified by some tag ( ‘meta’ or better something more self-explaining) and will make new users aware about the place where such questions should be discussed.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree that meta questions should be included on the sites.

- Should Stack Overflow have related Server Fault questions?
- Should Server Fault have related Super User questions?

Anyway, cross-site related queries is far beyond the scope of anything we'll be able to do anytime soon.

Comment: I'm not talking about generalized cross domain search results, but picking one or two meta questions that have a high match to the question being asked. The goal being to reduce the attack on new users and actually help them find the information they need quickly. It also introduces them to the meta site where they can post future questions.

Comment: If the search hints you're displaying when users ask a question is already JSON/XML it shouldn't be too hard to include one or two results from another domain.

Comment: I am all for improving the default FAQ to address the most common new user pain points, but not this.

Comment: @Jeff I am guessing based on your comments there is no way we can do a search across all three sites at once? Was going to post that as a suggestion. Single page with the ability to search all three sites with one user account.